# Facebook Friend invite is sent successfully but no data received in response in facebook-sdk.4.0 android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
            String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;
            final String TAG = "fbv4";
            appLinkUrl = "https://fb.me/1161673067......";
            previewImageUrl = "mydomain.com/my_invite_image.jpg";

            if (AppInviteDialog.canShow())
            {
                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                        .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                        .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                        .build();
                AppInviteDialog.show(MainActivity.this, content);
                AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
                appInviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess result = " + result.getData().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel()
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError message = "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                appInviteDialog.show(content);
            }
```

This is my code for facebook invite friend with facebook-sdk.4.0. My invite dialog is open correctly with friendlist and showing invite is send correctly but no invite get to friend. get success in log all process is going correct but i don't get any notification of my app.

Comment: The recipient may have blocked all app invites.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30374275/3647974 might this one help ?

Comment: yes it will work need to change setting of are account

Comment: @ShaymaPathan, did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @zephyr Please check answer i have added may it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zephyr

Yes, I was facing notification blocking issue from facebook user settings please try this so maybe it will helpful for you as well as it was worked for me.

```
Click in the top right of Facebook and select Settings
Click Notifications in the left menu
Click Edit next to On Facebook
Click Edit next to App requests and activity
Click to set the notifications for the app or game to On
```