# How send Android app requests to Facebook friends (to install app) that is not published on Google Play?

Tags: android, facebook

I tried what mentioned in [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) link. I successfully made my app to invite friends on Facebook, but none of friends did receive an invite.

I tried logging in a device that does not have my app installed and logged in with an unauthorized Facebook friend's account according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30345543) question. Still there are no notifications.

I wonder it may be cause my app is not published on Google Play and Facebook doesn't bother to send notification from such an app to its users.
I got the app link URL from Facebook:

```
appLinkUrl = "https://fb.me/***078833387****"
```

But when opened in browser it redirects to Google Play and says:

> We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved finally.

It was cause my app was not made public in Facebook. I made it public under AppReview tab of my app page [here](https://developers.facebook.com).

Got the clue from [this](http://www.i-visionblog.com/2015/04/app-invites-for-android-apps-facebook-f8.html) site.

Comment: since I didn't upload my app in google play, when my friend clicks the install button, it shows error.